# Uploading Spatial 10x data into seurat

Tags: r, spatial, seurat

I am trying to upload my 10X Visium data into R so that I can create a Seurat object but for some reason by data has not been able to be uploaded. I am using the code from the Satija lab to load the data

```
Load10X_Spatial(
  data.dir,
  filename = "filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5",   #here I have the h5 file for the filtered but I was wondering how would I also get the images to be uploaded as well because the output from the spaceranger has a folder called "Spatial" but I was not sure. 
  assay = "Spatial",
  slice = "slice1",
  filter.matrix = TRUE, 
  to.upper = FALSE,
  image = NULL,
  ...
)
```

Comment: I think you are trying to "read" data into R, rather than "upload" it. I would suggest asking this question at [Seurat Discussions](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/discussions), since it is more to do with how to use specialised software than with R programming.